# simple linker error, can't find solution

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm a bit new to C++ but this should be really simple for someone with a bit more experience to find, as I've been staring at it for a while now.

I have a class that has another class instance as an ivar:

```
private:
Test test1;
```

Then I have `test.hpp`:

```
class Test{
int x;
void tester();
public:
Test(); //constructor
};
```

And `test.cpp`:

```
 Test::Test():x(5){
    tester();
}

void Test::tester(){
std::cout<<x;
}
```

When I attempt to run, I get this:

`Test::Test() referenced from <my original class with the test1 ivar> not found in architecture`

Now I have plenty of other C++ code working fine, so the "architecture," whatever that means, is clearly supporting the language fine (I'm using Xcode).

What could be causing this linker error?

Comment: Are you sure your test class cpp file has been compiled, and is actually linked with the final executable?

Comment: oh my goodness, thanks. Somehow in Xcode the box "assign to target" didn't get added automatically for the cpp. feel free to make your comment and answer and i'll accept.

Comment: By the way, next time, for that king of question, please use the Xcode tag so we know which IDE you are using. But only use it if it has something to do with the IDE usage... : )

Comment: Incidentally, "ivar" is an Objective-C-ism. In C++ it's a data member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the C++ file containing your test class is compiled and is actually linked with the final executable.

In Xcode, it means assigning the C++ file to the target.